# PowerShell: extract timestamp from string

Tags: powershell

I am brand new to PowerShell and have figured out how to extract a relevant line from a log file:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\SyncToy\2.0\SyncToyLog.log:325:SYNC: 05/22/2012 14:54:55:857: SyncToy run of Profile Backup (C:\Documents and Settings\admin\, H:\Sync\) completed at 5:22/2012 2:54:55 PM.
```

What I would like to do is extract the first timestamp sans milliseconds (the one that uses 24 hour time) to a variable. Result:

```
05/22/2012 14:54:55
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to parse out the date/time string with a regular expression and then convert it to a date/time object:

```
$line = 'C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\SyncToy\2.0\SyncToyLog.log:325:SYNC: 05/22/2012 14:54:55:857: SyncToy run of Profile Backup (C:\Documents and Settings\admin\, H:\Sync\) completed at 5:22/2012 2:54:55 PM.'

$dateTimeString = [regex]::Matches($line, '(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d.+): ')[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Then convert it to a datetime object:

```
$provider = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo "en-US"

$dateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateTimeString, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff', $provider)
```

Now you can display it or store it in a variable however you want:

```
$dateTime -f 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
```

Comment: You're amazing. That worked perfectly. I spent at least a couple hours this afternoon trying to figure this out... cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

or simply:

```
($line -split ':\s+|:\d{3,}')[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

with above references, I could do following in my case

## I have log file(s) with data lines like below

DefaultSource;Verbose;8;9/5/2016 1:05:19 PM;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
DefaultSource;Verbose;8;9/5/2016 1:05:20 PM;yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
DefaultSource;Verbose;8;9/5/2016 1:05:20 PM;zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

PS C:\> $lines = Get-Content "~\Documents\FileName.log"

## Below line extracts pattern 'd/m/yyyy h:mm:ss [A/P]M' and shows all matching captures

PS C:\> $lines | %{[regex]::Matches($_,'(\d+/\d+/\d\d\d\d)\s(\d+:\d+:\d+)\s([AP]M)')} | Select captures

## Get the first value in DateTime Format

PS C:\> [datetime]$dd = ($lines | %{[regex]::Matches($_,'(\d+/\d+/\d\d\d\d)\s(\d+:\d+:\d+)\s([AP]M)')} | Select -First 1 Value).Value

PS C:\> $dd.GetType().FullName 
System.DateTime

PS C:\> $dd 
Monday, September 5, 2016 12:53:20 PM