# Regular Expression Match for dir with date in it not yielding $1, $2, $3 results

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to use a regular expression with powershell to extract the year, month and day from a directory name.  For some reason, I can tell I get the match with -match, but when I try to get the month, day, and year with [regex]::Matches, I can't obtain the matches.

```
      $temp = "toLocRobo_2019-01-30"
      $regex = [regex]::Matches($temp,'([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)')
      write-output $1 $2 $3  #$1, $2, and $3 are empty
      if($temp -match '([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)') { 
         write-output $1 $2 $3 #cursor gets to here so it matches, but $1, $2, and $3 are empty
      }
```

I've been looking at [powershell matches datestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710950/powershell-extract-timestamp-from-string) and [powershell regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html) but it's a little different and I'm not sure why it's not working. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The matches are contained in `$regex` but you don't even use that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are the $1, $2 and $3 vars filled?

Your regex works ok, see this code:

```
$temp = "toLocRobo_2019-01-30"
$regex = [regex]::Matches($temp, '([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)')
$regex.groups[0].value
$regex.groups[1].value
$regex.groups[2].value
$regex.groups[3].value
```

Comment: I like this best because it helps me to re-use the found matches.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `$1` etc. when performing replace actions. 
To simply match the date, I would do something like this:

```
$temp = "toLocRobo_2019-01-30"

# using named groups
if ($temp -match '(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<day>\d{1,2})') {
    Write-Output ("year: {0}, month: {1}, day: {2}" -f  $matches['year'],$matches['month'],$matches['day'])
}

# using numbered groups
if ($temp -match '(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})') {
    Write-Output ("year: {0}, month: {1}, day: {2}" -f  $matches[1],$matches[2],$matches[3])
}
```